# Changing the SSRS date picker format to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, power-bi-report-server

I have seen this issue posted a few times but there does not appear to be a solution for what I am seeing. I have a paginated SSRS report that requires a date input from the drop-down calendar. Upon entering, say, January 21st 2020, the UI is then displaying the date chosen as 1/21/2020, [for example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgms0.png) I need it to be 21/01/2020. Some points of note:
* all location settings for both the report server and the client browser are set to English (United Kingdom) and all date format settings are set to dd/mm/yyyy within the Windows settings on both the report server and client machine. All client browser language settings are English-UK in both IE and Chrome
* the variable is a DateTime data type
* this is a paginated SSRS report being displayed on a Power BI host server
* this is affecting all reports on this server
* the date field is not necessarily returned in the report, so converting the data is not applicable here.
* PBI version 15, SQL Server 2016
I have seen responses talking about expressing the field into the correct format, eg `=CDate(Fields!BirthDate.Value)` or `=FormatDateTime(Fields!BirthDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)` however this does not appear to change anything (when it doesn't error).

I'm at a total loss as to where this Americanization of the date is coming from. Any thoughts?

Comment: Last time I researched this (in a version of SSRS before the Power BI edition), it was baked into SSRS and there was nothing that could be done about it. I'm curious to see if there is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the report server's location settings and the user's browser's location settings don't (by default) do anything to the report formats because the report has its own `Language` property that is set by default to `en-US`. So unless you modify this property, you are always going to get US formats. You access this property on the report's Property panel.

Now you could set it to `en-UK` but a better solution is to set it to the user's internationali[s|z]ation setting by using `=User!Language`. Now you can use `d` as the cell `Format` property for the user's regional short date format.

Handy formats that use the user's regional formats are:

- d = short date format
- N2 = number with 2 decimal places
- N0 = number with no decimal places
- P0 = percent with no decimal places

Comment: Thank you Chris, that appears to have resolved it for me!